# Flutter: how to split a list of string that contain html tags using regex?

Tags: flutter, arraylist, mobile

I try to split the list of sentences which have html tags as below: 
The <a href="sy.com" id="sy">sky</a> is clear and the <a href="st.com" class="st">stars</a> are twinkling. 
They were <a href="etc.com" id="et">excited</a> to see their first sloth. 
Douglas figured the best way to <a href="etc.com" id="et">succeed</a> was to do the <a href="opt.com" class="op">opposite</a> of what he'd been doing all his life.

The result I want is as below:
[The, <a href="sy.com" id="sy">sky</a>, is clear and the, <a href="st.com" class="st">stars</a>, are twinkling.]
[They were, <a href="etc.com" id="et">excited</a>, to see their first sloth.]
[Douglas figured the best way to, <a href="etc.com" id="et">succeed</a>, was to do the, <a href="opt.com" class="op">opposite</a>, of what he'd been doing all his life.] 
How am I able to do it with RegExp in order to get above result?

Comment: only a tag are in that string?

Comment: Hi @eamirho3ein, can you elaborate more?

Comment: in your example I see only <a, is this only tag you want to get, or other html tag are included too?

Comment: only this <a tag

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/html - the docs say: "APIs for parsing and manipulating HTML content outside the browser"

Comment: Hi @pskink, instead of using the packages, I prefer to use Regex function.

Comment: How to use String.splitMapJoin? Any example?

Comment: it is a bit complicated to me as I'm beginner, how to apply that in my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example this is your string:

```
String str =
      "The <a href=\"sy.com\" id=\"sy\">sky</a> is clear and the <a href=\"st.com\" class=\"st\">stars</a> are twinkling. They were <a href=\"etc.com\" id=\"et\">excited</a> to see their first sloth.  Douglas figured the best way to <a href=\"etc.com\" id=\"et\">succeed</a> was to do the <a href=\"opt.com\" class=\"op\">opposite</a> of what he'd been doing all his life.";
```

you clan split it like this:

```
final reg = RegExp("<[^>]*>");
var result = str.split(reg);
print('result = $result'); // [The , sky,  is clear and the , stars,  are twinkling. They were , excited,  to see their first sloth.  Douglas figured the best way to , succeed,  was to do the , opposite,  of what he'd been doing all his life.]
```

if you want it with tag, try this(tanks to @JovenDev):

```
final reg = RegExp("(?=<a)|(?<=/a>)");
var result = str.split(reg);
print('result = $result'); // [The , <a href="sy.com" id="sy">sky</a>,  is clear and the , <a href="st.com" class="st">stars</a>,  are twinkling. They were , <a href="etc.com" id="et">excited</a>,  to see their first sloth.  Douglas figured the best way to , <a href="etc.com" id="et">succeed</a>,  was to do the , <a href="opt.com" class="op">opposite</a>,  of what he'd been doing all his life.]
```

Comment: I try that before, but I want to keep the <a tag instead of remove it. <a href=\"sy.com\" id=\"sy\">sky</a>, this is what I need

Comment: Hi @eamirho3ein, any idea on it?

Comment: I able to resolve it using RegExp("(?=<a)|(?<=/a>)")

Comment: wow, nice. I will update my answer with yours so other people find it easier.